# Why is Kabbalah sometimes referred to as "derech ha'emes"?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

The Ramban (and others) often refer to *pshatim* that are of *kabbalistic* nature as being *al derech ha'emes*. Here is one example from Vayikra 23:36:

> ועל **דרך האמת** כי ששת ימים עשה ה' את השמים ואת הארץ (שמות כ יא) ויום השביעי הוא שבת ואין לו בן זוג וכנסת ישראל היא בת זוגו שנאמר ואת הארץ והנה היא שמינית "עצרת היא" כי שם נעצר הכל וצוה בחג המצות שבעה ימים בקדושה לפניהם ולאחריהם כי כולם קדושים ובתוכם ה' ומנה ממנו תשעה וארבעים יום שבעה שבועות כימי עולם וקדש יום שמיני כשמיני של חג והימים הספורים בינתים כחולו של מועד בין הראשון והשמיני בחג והוא יום מתן תורה שהראם בו את אשו הגדולה ודבריו שמעו מתוך האש ולכך יקראו רבותינו ז"ל בכל מקום חג השבועות עצרת כי הוא כיום שמיני של חג שקראו הכתוב כן וזהו מאמרם (חגיגה יז) שמיני רגל בפני עצמו הוא לענין פז"ר קש"ב ותשלומין דראשון הוא כי הוא אצילות הראשונים ואינו כאחדות שלהם ולכך יזכיר בפרשת כל הבכור (דברים טז טו) בשלש רגלים חג המצות וחג השבועות וחג הסוכות שבעת ימים ולא יזכיר השמיני כי שם אמר יראה כל זכורך וגו' והנה זה מבואר

Why are *pshatim* that are *kabbalistic* referred to as *as derech ha'emes*?

Comment: Many Ramban's commentaries are of Kabbalic nature, but על דרך האמת is just a figurative expression. Ramban didn't have Zohar and Kabbalah, but did have some traditions.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to name something controversial "Truth" [or "[authentic] tradition"]?

Comment: The idiom probably parallels the English expression "in truth" which usually indicates an unexpected but more fundamentally accurate explanation.

Comment: It's only the word *emet* that refers to kabbalah. The word *derekh* here introduces the name of a mode of interpretation. You could say, e.g., *al derekh pshat*.

Answer (score 1):

The following responsum of [R. Yosef Messas](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%A9) may be relevant:

**[Otzar Hamichtavim 3:1627](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22016&st=&pgnum=107&hilite=)**

> מכתבו הבהיר הגיעני בו שאל כבודו מדוע קורין לספר הזוהר זוהר הקדש מה שאין קורין אפי' לספר התנ"ך
>
> תשובה דע בני כי ספר הזוהר קם עליו ערער בכמה זמנים מי מחברו ורבו הדעות עד כי הרבה החליטו שהמקובל מהר"מ קורדווירו זצ"ל הוא שחברו ונתלה באילן גדול הרשב"י זיע"א מפני שנחבא י"ג שנים במערה כידוע בש"ס וזכורני שראיתי שנשאל על זה הגאון יעב"ץ אשכנזי זצ"ל והשיב שלא יוכל להכריע ואך הוא ספר מלא דברים טובים יהיה מחברו מי שיהיה ואמנם ידי זרים שלטו בו ולקה בחליף וחסר ויתיר ע"כ
>
> ואמנם בל העוסקים בקבלה תלו כל חכמתם בו וממנו שואבים כל קבלותם ומתחלה היה שמו אצלם מדרש רשב"י זצ"ל כמו פרקי ר"א ושוב כדי לחבבו על העם ולהפיצו בישראל שנו את שמו לספר הזוהר ע"ש הכתוב (דניאל י"ב) והמשכילים יזהירו כזוהר הרקיע וכו' ועוד באו אחרים והוסיפו לו תואר הקדודש להוסיף לו חבה על חבה כמו שמתארים ס' של"ה הקדוש ולאור החיים על התורה הקדוש ועוד הרבה כדי להרים ערכם אצל העם כדי לקרותם או לקנותם או שניהם יחדו וכן מתארים חברה קדישא לחבבה על כל מין חברה מה שאין כן התנ"ך והש"ס והמדרש שהם תמיד מאז חביבין וקדושים בעיני העם
>
> His bright letter reached me, in it His Honor asked why we call the book of the Zohar "The Holy Zohar" (Zohar Hakadosh), something which we don't even call the book of Tanach.
>
> Answer: Know, my son, that a protest against the book of the Zohar has risen up on many occasions — who is it's author? — and the opinions have augmented, to the point where many have determined that the kabbalist R. Moshe Cordovero of blessed memory was the author, and he attributed it to R. Shimon Bar Yochai (his merit should protect us) because [R. Shimon Bar Yochai] hid in a cave for 13 years, as is known in the Talmud. And I recall that the genius R. Yaakov Emden of blessed memory was asked about this and he responded that he is unable to reach a conclusion, but the book is filled with good things whoever the author may be, but  the hands of strangers have ruled over it and struck it with a sharp knife and removed and added [to it], end quote.
>
> However, all who engage in kaballah attribute all their wisdom to it, and from it they draw all their traditions, and originally their name for it was "The Midrash of R. Shimon Bar Yochai", just like "The Pirkei of R. Eliezer". And then in order to endear it to the people and to spread it in Israel they changed its name to "The Book of the Zohar", referencing the verse (Daniel Chapter 12) "And the wise ones will shine like the shining of the sky etc.". And then others came and added on the appellation "Holy" to it, in order to add endearment to its endearment, just like they added the appellation "Holy" to the book of the Shelah and the Ohr Hachaim on the Torah and man others, in order to increase their value to the people, so that they would read them and buy them, or both. And similarly they appellated the Chevrah Kadisha in order to endear it beyond all other groups. As opposed to the Tanach and the Talmud and the Midrash, which were always dear and holy in the eyes of the people.

Perhaps for the same reason kabbalistic answers are specifically called "the truth".

Answer (score 0):

Recently, a friend showed me a *maareh mekomos* sheet that he made. One of his footnotes reads as follows:

> In a הספד for Rav Moshe Shapiro Zt'l in the Mir, Rav Aharon Lopiansky explained that the reason why the Ramban refers to *penimiyus HaTorah* as the "*derech haemes*" is because all other forms of תורה are describing periphery details about the ענינים .
>   They are ancillary to the core truth, they describe details around the center point, but not the center point itself.
>   Whereas *penimiyus HaTorah* goes straight to the core and describes the center point. It describes the essence of חכמה